# How to add own elements (text, etc.) to Azure AD B2C Language Customization?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

The *Language Customization* feature in Azure AD B2C is currently in preview and allows only simple customization of elements of the SignIn / SignUp pages.

How can I add my own elements to these pages - e.g. some explanation text, footer, disclaimer etc. - which also can then be localized to the languages enabled/supported within the policy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've outlined, Azure AD B2C's *Language Customization* feature only allows you to customize pre-existing text, you can't add your own text via that feature.

What you can do is have your own [custom UIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization), add your own elements there and implement localization based for those custom elements using the `?locale` query string parameter that's included in the request B2C makes to retrieve your custom UI page.

Comment: I want to modify existing text but not able to do this.
look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60707992/customising-the-message-error-text-in-azure-ad-b2c-custom-policies