# Customising the message/error text in Azure AD B2C custom policies

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I want to Customizing the message/error text in Azure AD B2C custom policie,Not getting a proper way to do this.has anyone done this in their B2C custom Policies

I want to customize the **Verification is necessary. Please click Send button.** test which is under "**ver_intro_msg**" id ,
I added following to Building Block.
Let me know where it goes wrong

```
    <ContentDefinition Id="api.localaccountsignup">
    <Metadata>
    <Item Key="DisplayName">Local account sign up page</Item>
  </Metadata>

  <LocalizedResourcesReferences MergeBehavior="Prepend">
    <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="en" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="api.localaccountsignup.en" />
  </LocalizedResourcesReferences>
  </ContentDefinition>
    </ContentDefinitions>
    <Localization Enabled="true">
  <SupportedLanguages DefaultLanguage="en" MergeBehavior="ReplaceAll">
    <SupportedLanguage>en</SupportedLanguage>
  </SupportedLanguages>
  <LocalizedResources Id="api.localaccountsignup.en">
    <LocalizedStrings>
  <LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="ver_intro_msg">Wellcome to Buckman Compliance Portal</LocalizedString>
  <LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="ver_info_msg">Cheak Your Regisered Mail For OTP</LocalizedString>
    </LocalizedStrings>
  </LocalizedResources>
</Localization>
```

Comment: Are you passing the query parameter `ui_locales=en` as part of your auth request?

Comment: @JasSuri Yes..Do i need to add something else in building block other then what i mentioned ??

Comment: Policy looks ok. Can you share the complete files minus any confidential data?

Comment: @AlfredoRevilla here is my file link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wwRc3yVJgSl2C629UiRGBFK6pRXq-WZm/view?usp=sharing ,kindly suggest something, ihave tried many many times.

Comment: @RohitChouhan send your base policy too. I copied the relevant elements and ver_intro_msg was replace by yours.

Comment: @RohitChouhan here is how it looks (click the sign up now link): https://alfredowhoiamb2c1.b2clogin.com/AlfredoWhoiamB2C1.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_signup_signin/api/CombinedSigninAndSignup/unified?local=signup&csrf_token=RFFTMWlkdWZvWmR1MUhoR0w2aEhiNHNWZ1loeE54MWVkbThsRmo2Vm9NbUE4eVJZRjExVWVERXptTFZHQlFMSlZIbUdpNHNpSmpJVWFRY3RoRmlGQ1E9PTsyMDIwLTAzLTI0VDE0OjQwOjA2LjgxNDU0NjlaO2ZEa2ZHcmFKcXl3OUo5djVXdC9tb1E9PTt7Ik9yY2hlc3RyYXRpb25TdGVwIjoxfQ==&tx=StateProperties=eyJUSUQiOiJkMjllNmQwYi1mOGRmLTQzMmUtOTc3Zi0yOTZkN2U1ZWY0YTgifQ&p=B2C_1A_signup_signin

Comment: @AlfredoRevilla here is my base policy https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zCnAflF6NFrmpK91KaTba5e3ZS_1nwgA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @AlfredoRevilla I followed this sample:  https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/passwordless-email
Do i also need to change something in base policy or somewhere else???
Thanks

Comment: @RohitChouhan should not be neccesary. I was asking it in case you changed it. Let me try that template and come back to you.

Comment: @AlfredoRevilla can you cheak this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60975989/avoid-verification-code-emails-when-the-user-is-not-registered-in-azure-ad-b2c/60983716?noredirect=1#comment107932604_60983716

Comment: @RohitChouhan could you solve your first issue? I still need to go trough the provided template. Also I will take a look to the latest.

Comment: @AlfredoRevilla Yes I got solution for first issue, fro second one somehow I achieve the goal but still looking for a proper solution .