# Avoid verification code emails when the user is not registered in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Azure B2C is gives a false impression that the user is in the directory when they try to reset their password.

Following is steps in reset password:
1) User clicks the Reset Password link

2) B2C presents a page with “Email Address” field and says “Verification is necessary. Please click Send button.”

3) User enters his email address and clicks “Send Verification Code”

4) B2C sends the verification code this that email address (Even if no user is associated with that email address. This is where the user thinks he is registered with the system)

5) Now the user enters the verification code he received and click “Verify Code”

6) B2C validated the code and says “E-mail address verified. You can now continue” (This is the step where they become confident that they exist in the system)

7) Now when the users click “Continue” they get the error “An account could not be found for the provided user ID.” As given in the screenshot.

Confirming an email that is not associated with a user completely confuses them.
i found [this](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/pwd-reset-email-exists) solution but not getting exactly how to use these policy along with my [current policy](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/passwordless-email)

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this solution](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/pwd-reset-email-exists), you need to use the following XML snippet to implement it:

```
<Action Id="SendCode">
    <ValidationClaimsExchange>
        <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress-emailAddress" />
        <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AadSspr-SendCode">
        <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
            <Value>objectId</Value>
            <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
            </Precondition>
        </Preconditions>
        </ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile>
    </ValidationClaimsExchange>
</Action>
```

So you should begin with adding "emailVerificationControl" into the "LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress" TechnicalProfile.

Just adding [line 163-165](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/85145ac19af1a045fac8ff1ff3e0a4b4495807a1/policies/pwd-reset-email-exists/policy/TrustFrameworkExtensionsPwdResetAcctExists.xml#L163) to the place behind [line 890](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/85145ac19af1a045fac8ff1ff3e0a4b4495807a1/policies/passwordless-email/policy/TrustFrameworkBase.xml#L890).

And you need to add [DisplayControls](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/85145ac19af1a045fac8ff1ff3e0a4b4495807a1/policies/pwd-reset-email-exists/policy/TrustFrameworkExtensionsPwdResetAcctExists.xml#L48) into your TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml file so that it could be referenced.

If there are any other references, you should also add them to the corresponding position.

Comment: however i am able to upload policy without any error but its throwing an error "500 - Internal server error." i have made all possible changes and references.

Comment: @RohitChouhan Can you share your extension file? Sometimes even if the file can be uploaded successfully, there is still something wrong with the content.

Comment: here is my extension file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-7t_dgISZm-xkF4rIHsgs3uBw03vjz8V/edit  ,please have a look and let me know what i am missing here.

Comment: @allean Wu please let me know what exactly we need to change in User journey

Comment: @SaurabhSrivastava can you tell me what all changes you have done,if possible kindly share your extension file hiding private data.

Comment: Hi @Rohit, I exactly copy all the content mentioned here :https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/pwd-reset-email-exists. Changed the basic informations and it worked.