# B2C Multilingual issue, success/failure message are displayed in english in place of selected ui_locales language

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, multilingual, aad-b2c

B2C Multilingual issue, Am setting the language to "gu" i.e. Gujarati, the content is converted to "gu" but the success/failure message are displayed in english language. I want it to be in "gu".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to > [User flows and custom policies in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-overview)

> User flows are predefined, built-in, configurable policies that we
> provide so you can create sign-up, sign-in, and policy editing
> experiences in minutes.
>
> **Custom policies** enable you to create your own user journeys for
> complex identity experience scenarios

[image]

The [Localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization) element allows you to support multiple locales or languages in the policy for the user journeys. The localization support in policies allows you to:

•   Set up the explicit list of the supported languages in a policy and pick a default language.

•   Provide language-specific strings and collections.

[image]

Use a verification display control to verify a claim, for example an email address or phone number, with a verification code sent to the user.([Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/display-control-verification))

[image]

See code [Localization string IDs - Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization-string-ids#verification-display-control-user-interface-elements)  and default values and customize  the language in custom policy for the preferred language.

```html
<LocalizedResources Id="api.localaccountsignup.gu">
   <LocalizedStrings>
       <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="emailVerificationControl" StringId="success_send_code_msg">Customize the error message in gujarati</LocalizedString>

//for error messages you can use element type as ErrorMessage
    <LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" StringId="UserMessageIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">Your customized error message in language enabled</LocalizedString>

   <!-- Display control UI elements-->
    <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="emailVerificationControl" StringId="intro_msg"> Customize the error message in gujarati </LocalizedString>

  </LocalizedStrings>
</LocalizedResources>
```

Please do check this [Azure b2c Custom Policies Error Message - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/178990/azure-b2c-custom-policies-error-message.html) and similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60707992/customising-the-message-error-text-in-azure-ad-b2c-custom-policies) which may give an idea.

Pass the query parameter ui_locales=en as part of your authentication request. Replace it with preferred language as a part of your end point.

Other reference:
[customising-the-message-error-text-in-azure-ad-b2c-custom-policies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60707992/customising-the-message-error-text-in-azure-ad-b2c-custom-policies)